# Whether Spring boot Data JPA uses hibernate internally for it's implementation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working to set up an existing project, I found the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but there is no any dependency for hibernate so how to check whether a project using hibernate or not.

And Also I found JpaConfiguration class which contains following code.

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

        String entities = ClassUtils.getPackageName(ArkonnApplication.class);
        String converters = ClassUtils.getPackageName(Jsr310JpaConverters.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{entities, converters});

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlAuto);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", formatSql);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", useSqlComments);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

if this project is using the hibernate then why there is no any dependency or configuration for it.

1) Is Spirng boot Data JPA comes with default Hibernate configuration ?.

2) If yes, how spring boot Data JPA work internally with Hibernate.(any reference link)

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` will resolve all dependencies of your project. There you should be able to see the `hibernate` dependency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPA is an interface and Hibernate is the implementation. By default, Spring uses Hibernate as the default JPA vendor. you can see hibernate related dependency in dependency hierarchy under the pom.xml, this will resolve all dependencies of your project.

Answer (score 1):

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` comes with `hibernate` as default. In my comment above, from your project's workspace folder open a terminal/cmd and issue:

`mvn dependency:tree`

This will resolve all dependencies of your project. There you should be able to see the hibernate dependency.

Also from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa `pom.xml` in the dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring boot the jpa properties should be added to the application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    #url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    url: jdbc:h2:~/nexin;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
    username: nexin
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      show_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /console
  logging:
    config: classpath:logback.xml
```

If you do a mvn dependency:tree on you project to look at the dependencies spring jpa has pulled in you'll see hibernate is in there:

```
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
```